# Can I use polyfit with a range instead of a scalar for parameter N?

Tags: matlab, range, octave

The [`polyfit`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) function expects a scalar value for the polynomial degree `n`, e.g.

```
P = polyfit(X, Y, 3)
```

which suggests a `for` loop should be used to determine a range of polynomials (say degree 2 to degree 4) fitting the same curve:

```
% Fit a given curve with a series of polynomials
% of given degrees

X = 1:6; % Range of x in the sample
Y0 = [10, 11, 21, 2, 3, 7]; % Sample
DEG = 2:6; % Degrees to use for polynomials

plot(X, Y0) % Plot sample for reference
for n = DEG
  hold on
  P = polyfit(X, Y0, n); % Fitting polynomial, degree n
  Y = polyval(P, X); % Compute y for this polynomial
  plot(X, Y)
endfor
```

Is there a way to simplify this code and turn it into 'all array' by using the range DEG directly in the function? I tried several variation around `polyfit(X, Y0, DEG)`, but Octave keeps telling me:

```
error: polyfit: N must be a non-negative integer
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is, but also there is no real reason not to loop actually.

Comment: The output of `polyfit` is a row vector of length `n+1`. If `n` changes the output will have a different size. In principle, the output could be returned as a cell array, but Matlab's functions don't often include this sort of complexity (and there would still be a `for` loop hidden inside the function anyway).

Comment: In addition to the other comments. Fitting a polynomial of degree >2 to the data (`[X,Y0]`) seems quite a lot like overfitting and degrees >=5 will be interpolations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `arrayfun` is for:

```
octave:1> X = 1:6;
octave:2> Y0 = [10, 11, 21, 2, 3, 7];
octave:3> DEG = 2:6;
octave:4> arrayfun (@(n) polyfit (X, Y0, n), DEG, "UniformOutput", false)
ans =
{
  [1,1] =

     -0.37500    0.96786   11.30000

  [1,2] =

      1.0833  -11.7500   35.3095  -16.0000

  [1,3] =

      0.43750   -5.04167   17.43750  -18.94048   15.50000

  [1,4] =

      -1.2750    22.7500  -150.9583   456.2500  -612.7667   296.0000

  [1,5] =

     -0.31438    5.32693  -32.26604   80.10905  -54.29889  -58.20494   69.64828

}
```